# Urllib trouble across platforms

Tags: python, networking

On Linux, `urllib.urlopen("https://www.facebook.com/fql.php?query=SELECT first_name FROM user")` will have the spaces automatically quoted and run smoothly.
(By the way, the URL is fictional)

However on mac, this is not the case. Somehow the URL is **not** escaped, and an error would be thrown. I have checked both python versions to be at least 2.6 and the version of urllib to be 1.17

Is this a bug?

Comment: Also, why aren't you using `urllib2`?

Comment: also your fictional URL is scary, I suggest you change it :)

Comment: @MK: It's like from that anecdote - teacher meets parents of a boy asking them: is your son's name really `DROP TABLE pupils`?

Comment: @Tomasz know your sources please: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @MK: Thanks, I didn't know the source really, it was just sitting in my head :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

urlopen documentation doesn't promise you to escape anything.  Use urllib.quote() to escape it yourself.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. The troublesome thing is that I have to manually quote just the args part (if you quote the whole url it will turn http:// into http%3a// which is really annoying)